# Navigating to a DataURI in angular2 through a function

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to call a function that will trigger a file download in angular2. This data is stored in memory of the angular2 app (not on the server.  Based on what I've read i need to create a data uri
Here is my code that does this.

`downloadData() {
    let data="bacon,goodness";
    let uri = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(data));
    this.download=uri;
    window.location.href = uri;
  }`

My issue is that I cannot run the command

'window.location.href=uri'

It gives the error 
'SafeUrl' is not assignable to string
Is there another way to navigate to SafeUrl from inside a function

Comment: window.open(uri) ?

Comment: Same issue.  window.open expects a string.

Comment: you probably need to get the string of you url. Can you call uri.getSafeUrlString() ?

Comment: Yeah. that method doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave up on using sanitize.  The only way the api allows you to use a safeURL is as a parameter to [href]. This apparently was on purpose for security.

I do this now:

```
window.location.href =  "data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8," + encodeURIComponent(data);
```